# Which are the best plugins to import 3d model like obj in After Effects?

Tags: 3d, plug-in

Best plugin like video copilot to import 3d model like obj in after effects. I need a light weight plugin which need low graphics.

After affects 2017 doesn't support import of 3d obj or another model file.
But some plugins can import it. I need light weight plugin because video copilot is very high graphic plugin.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.